# Drama: Can't restore entire system using déja dup. (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Tags: 14.04, backup, restore, deja-dup

Yesterday I ran some updates on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and suddenly it kept telling me that system errors had been encountered. It got worse: the windows started flickering, I couldn't see my cursor, I couldn't shut down or restart the normal way at all.

Since I had been making backups (using the backup tool that comes with Ubuntu) and they were safe on an external hard drive, I proceeded to wipe my disc and re-installed Ubuntu.

Now I have tried to restore my system to its previous state using the deja-dup file and again the backup tool, but after beginning as one would expect, I soon get the lock screen and when I unlock it, there is no sign of the backup having taken place or taking place, it is as if I had just started the computer with the fresh installation.

One thing I do see now is that my firefox bookmarks are back, but that is all the change I can see.

What is happening here? I really hope I didn't do anything wrong and have now lost all my more recent data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after panicking for a while I have been able to retrieve the data. I found This tip on https://wiki.gnome.org/DejaDup/Help/Restore/Full :

> **General Fallback**
>   If for whatever reason, you have a problem after trying to restore with the “Restore files to original locations” option, try restoring again to a temporary directory and moving your files to where they belong.

I did that and it worked. Phew! Maybe this helps someone else in the future...

Comment: A general rule of thumb is to actually verify your whole backup procedure and restore randomly-picked files from time to time. If you have a spare machine you should also verify a full restore to that spare machine.

Comment: Definitely. The built-in "Backups" tool occasionally tests the backed-up files, so I thought I was good (and the files were okay, for some reason I needed to use the little trick described on the site linked above. Thank you!